# Zend Form 1.x using html5 datalist tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, zend-framework

Using Zend Form 1.x is possible to construct a form with a datalist tag like this:

```html
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

example here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

There is a Zend Form class that produce the above html?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such form element that is shipped by default with the ZF1 that can be used to create provided html. But you can create your own custom form element. And you also can take the Zend_Form_Element_Select as a example (as it looks almost the same).
How to create own elements describe in the documentation here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.custom
Good luck!